# What does the -I option do in a g++ call?

Tags: g++, compilation

I'm having a hard time finding good documentation on the most common g++ options.  I have the following g++ command and I'm trying to understand it well:

```
g++ q1.cpp -o q1 -I/usr/local/include/opencv -L/usr/local/lib -lm -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc
```

What does the `-I` option do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-I` adds to the path for searching for include files.

`-l` links to a particular library. (e.g. -lm links libm which is math)

Comment: Oh, that was a capital "i". Impossible to tell, in that font. (By which I mean the font my browser used, YMMV of course.)

Comment: So for each new path for include files, do I need a new -I(path_here) option?  Also, what about -L?

Comment: @kindle, the `-L` adds search paths for libraries.  There's no reason a particular `-I` flag would require  you to have a `-l` flag, unless you need to link against a particular library.

Answer (score 0):

It's not for a library I think it's only for include files. (It's a `i` not a `l`, `l` it's for libraries)